# i want a button in my html page on clicking the button it works same as a tab button

Tags: jquery, html

I want to be able to cycle through a list of elements using a single button event, the same way that you can cycle through elements in a form using the tab button on your keyboard.

```
<input type="text" class="ans4" style="border-color:#000;">
<input type="text" class="ans5" style="border-color:#000;">
<input type="text" class="ans6" style="border-color:#000;">

<input type="button" class="tab" value="Tab"/>
```

Comment: i am new in jquery kindly help

Comment: So what was the question again?

Comment: i want to make a button class tab.on clicking the button it does same work that of a tab button in keyboard

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/tabs/

Comment: So you want to simulate a tab press by clicking a button? where the tab have to appear? in every input field or in a specific one?

Comment: in every input type="text"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Simulate pressing tab key with jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9214125/simulate-pressing-tab-key-with-jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired with this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7668525/is-there-a-jquery-selector-to-get-all-elements-that-can-get-focus#answer-7668761) from [lee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/416630/lee), by selecting 'focusable' elements (and knowing which one is currently in focus) we can simulate TAB press and move focus to next one. [Fiddle example here](http://jsfiddle.net/t4ce2jtu/1/), using following HTML:

```
<fieldset class="tab_area">
    <legend>Tab works here</legend>
    <p><input type="text" /></p>
    <p><input type="text" /></p>
    <p><input type="text" /></p>
    <p>More info <a href="#" title="Link">here</a></p>
    <p>
        <select>
            <option value="1">Option 1</option>
            <option value="2">Option 2</option>
        </select>
    </p>
</fieldset>
<p><input type="button" class="tab" value="Click me to Tab" /></p>
```

and JS:

```
var focusAbles = $('.tab_area').find('a[href], area[href], input:not([disabled]), select:not([disabled]), textarea:not([disabled]), button:not([disabled]), iframe, object, embed, *[tabindex], *[contenteditable]');
$('.tab').on('mousedown', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var inFocus = $(':focus');
    if (inFocus.length) {
        var focusIndex = focusAbles.index(inFocus);
        if (focusIndex + 1 < focusAbles.length) {
            focusAbles.eq(focusIndex + 1).focus();
        } else {
            focusAbles.eq(0).focus();
        };
    } else {
        focusAbles.eq(0).focus();
    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is a simple snippet to show how you can utilise JQuery to display an 'active' tab by clicking on one.

```js
$('.tab').click(function(){
  $('.tab').removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");
  });
```

```css
.tab{
  display:inline-block;
  background:blue;
  height:50px;
  width:100px;
  }
.active{
  background:red;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tab">1</div>
<div class="tab">2</div>
<div class="tab">3</div>
<div class="tab">4</div>
<div class="tab">5</div>
```

---

Below is a snippet showing this using a button and iterating through them.

```js
$('.but').click(function() {
  var len = $('.parent').children().length;
  var next = $('.active').next();
  var thi = next.index();
  $('.tab').removeClass("active");
  if (thi != -1) {
    $(next).addClass("active");
  } else {
    $('.parent').children().first().addClass("active");
  }
});
```

```css
.tab {
  display: inline-block;
  background: blue;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100px;
}
.active {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="tab active">1</div>
  <div class="tab">2</div>
  <div class="tab">3</div>
  <div class="tab">4</div>
  <div class="tab">5</div>
</div>
<button class="but">click me!</button>
```

Comment: I think the OP is looking for an event to fire on specific keypress, in this case "tab". Going by this response to my question "i want to make a button class tab.on clicking the button it does same work that of a tab button in keyboard "

Comment: no i wan t the event to fire on clicking a button in a web page whose functionality is same as tab button

Answer (score 0):

```
Try the below code 

**HTML**

<input type="text" data-tab-index="1" class="answer ans4" style="border-color:#000;"></br></br>
<input type="text" data-tab-index="2" class="answer ans5" style="border-color:#000;"></br></br>
<input type="text" data-tab-index="3" class="answer ans6" style="border-color:#000;"></br></br>

<input type="button" class="tab"id="btnTab" value="Tab"/>

**Java Script**

$(document).ready(function() {
    var tabIndex = 0;
    $("#btnTab").click(function(e) {
        setFocus();
    });

    function setFocus() {

        var isFocusDone = false;
        $(".answer").each(function(index) {
            var dataTabIndex = parseInt($(this).attr("data-tab-index"));
            if ((tabIndex + 1) == dataTabIndex) {
                $(this).focus();
                tabIndex = dataTabIndex;
                isFocusDone = true;
                return false;
            }
        });

        if (!isFocusDone) {
            $(".answer").each(function(index) {
                var dataTabIndex = parseInt($(this).attr("data-tab-index"));
                if (dataTabIndex == 1) {
                    $(this).focus();
                    tabIndex = dataTabIndex;
                    return false;
                }
            });
        }
    }

});
```