get first focusable element in container
It seems trivial but I can't find a solution that works without issues.
Consider a parent div, I want to get the first focusable element in this div.
Many edge cases to consider:

the child might be in a parent hierarchy that is disabled
the child might be in a parent hierarchy that is not visible / displayed
the child or some parent might have tabindex -1
the child might be in a parent hierarchy that is inert

And probably more?
Can someone find a solution that works and handles all edge cases?
It would be preferable if it didn't have to iterate everything.

Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/46917054/2181514  Likely doesn't handle parent that is disabled etc which it's unlikely you'll manage without some form of iteration.

No it doesn't handle some edge cases. Iteration is probably required if there is no selector only solution, but it would be preferable to exit early in it and avoid recursive calls on parent to improve performance. I tried many solutions on stackoverflow and found none that works well.

We imagine this is your container class : container
you may use this js: (Its complicated but that's because of your criteria)
firstFocusableElement = document.querySelector('input, select, textarea, button, object, a, area[href], [tabindex]')

Yeah, that's it. You have to know this is based on your edges, so you may not be able to for example click a disabled element, or focus on an Anchor without href, but you selected it!

you may not be able to focus - criteria 1, it's even in the title: get the first focusable element

suppose you have a div inside document that is display:none, and inside of it an input. Your selector would return the input even if it is inside a non displayed div, therefore not focusable, so it cannot fulfil the requirements. It could fail on other requirements as well. But kudos for trying, unlike the downvote bandwagon guys who can't even do that.

Here's something I wrote that's similar to what you want.  This only considers children that have display: none; styles, but you can add your additional conditions:
const isFocusable = (element) => 
  element instanceof HTMLAnchorElement ||
  element instanceof HTMLButtonElement ||
  element instanceof HTMLInputElement ||
  element instanceof HTMLTextAreaElement ||
  element instanceof HTMLSelectElement;

function findFirstFocusableDescendant(element) {
  if (!element) return;
  if (isFocusable(element)) return element;

  // Here you can tweak to also filter out disabled, tabindex=-1, and inert
  const visibleChildren = Array.from(element.children).filter(
    (child) => window.getComputedStyle(child).display !== "none"
  );

  for (const of visibleChildren) {
    const found = findFirstFocusableElement(child);
    if (found) return found;
  }
}

